# How to show the content of object on IE9

Tags: javascript

```
var obj = {'test1':"value1", "test2": "value2" }
console.log(obj);
```

**reuslt**

```
[object, Object]
```

Is is possible to show the content the object not to use JSON.stringify on IE9?
like the following

```
{'test1':"value1", "test2": "value2" }
```

Comment: JSON.stringify and JSON.parse were added native to the browser in IE8 - make sure that you're not running in IE7 compatibility mode and that the object you're attempting to stringify doesn't have circular references.

Comment: Eh, it is not too clear what you're asking... please, try to reformulate what you need.

Comment: What's your question? What's your source data? Your desired end result? You say `JSON.stringify` "does not work somehow". ***How*** does it not work? What does your code trying to use it look like? What error or other symptom do you get? Sorry, but this is all Asking Technical Questions 101.

Comment: I'm sure that my IE9 is running on standard mode....:(

Comment: You can't make a string just like that out of any object. What object exactly are you talking about?

Comment: As a side note - please use `@` to notify people when you reply to comments otherwise they won't see you have replied.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard I don't know about the object. I want to know it. That is why I am trying to show the content of the object

Comment: Try `console.dir()` instead of `console.log()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn: It's hard to tell with such a low quality question, but that might actually be an *answer* rather than a comment.

Comment: @TaichiSato see my answer for pure JavaScript way. (that works in older browsers as well)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using [`console.dir()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/console.dir) instead of `console.log()` - this will also work with other browsers' consoles.

See also the MSDN article [Internet Explorer 9 Developer Tools Deep Dive – Part 3: Debugging JavaScript](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbowen/archive/2011/06/24/internet-explorer-9-developer-tools-deep-dive-part-3-debugging-javascript.aspx?Redirected=true).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see what's in the complex object without using full scale library, you can use such code:

```
var complexObject = { 
    "first field": "first value", "second": function() {
        alert("hello");
    }, 
    "third": ["I", "am", "an", "array"]
};

var complexObjectString = "";
for (var key in complexObject) {
    complexObjectString += key + ": " + complexObject[key] + "\n";
}
alert(complexObjectString);​
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/8sR9B/).

Answer (score 0):

In IE9 you need to be in standards mode to use the JSON object; e.g., you must have a doctype.

This does not work: [Live copy](http://jsbin.com/obokez/2) | [source](http://jsbin.com/obokez/2/edit)

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Without a doctype</p>
<script>
(function() {

  try {
    var obj = {
      foo: "bar"
    };

    var str = JSON.stringify(obj);

    display("<code>" + str + "</code>");
  }
  catch (e) {
    display("Exception: " + (e.message || e.toString()));
  }

  function display(msg) {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = msg;
    document.body.appendChild(p);
  }
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

It fails with an error that `JSON` is undefined.

If you add

```
<!doctype html>
```

to the top, it works: [Live copy](http://jsbin.com/obokez/) | [source](http://jsbin.com/obokez/edit)